# Operator Preceedence and Logical Operator in Java

Tags: java, logical-operators

When I execute the below code I get the output given below. But according to java operator precedence && has higher preceedence than || so at first (boolb = true) && (boolc = true) should be evaluated but this is not being happened. Can you please tell me the reason and what is actually being happened behind scenes.

```
static boolean boola, boolb, boolc;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean bool = (boola = true) || (boolb = true) && (boolc = true);

    System.out.println("" + boola + boolb + boolc);
}
```

Expected results: `truetruetrue`

Actual result: `truefalsefalse`

Comment: Why would you use such a horrible piece of code in the first place? Assigning booleans inside boolean logic expressions is the best way to shoot yourself in the foot. Write simple, readable code.

Comment: the output i expect is truetruetrue but what jvm shows is truefalsefalse.@ernest_k

Comment: No one will use such a horrible code but in the process of learning I must go through such type of nasty codes.@JBNizet

Comment: So what you called "actual results" in your question is in fact your "expected" results? `||` is a short-circuit operation. If its first operand is true, it doesn't even evaluate the second one.

Comment: I made your code compile, and fixed your question.

Comment: @JBNizet. I know about short-circuit operation but && has higher preceedence than ||. So && must be evaluated first and then ||. Other problem is i used ( ) for assignment which has very high preceedence so all the variables are to be assigned to true. But it is not being done.

Comment: No, that's no what precedence means. It means that the expression will be evaluated as a || (b && c), and not as (a || b) && c. So a is evaluated first.

Answer (score 3):

`||` is a short-circuit operation. If its first operand is true, it doesn't even evaluate the second one.

The value of `(boola = true)` is true, and the evaluation just stops there. So the other booleans keep their original value: false.

Comment: But && is also a short circuit operator which is having higher preceedence than ||. So isn't && to be calculated first?

Comment: Another question ( ) has higher preceedence right? Then why all the assignments aren't being done first?

Comment: having higher precedence doesn't mean "to be evaluated first". it means that when evaluating a + b * c, then what is evaluated is a + (b * c) and not (a + b) * c. Same for boolean logic: a || b && c is evaluated as a || (b && c), and not as (a || b) && c.

Comment: You made my day. Thank you very much.